# Extract year and week number from H2 database

Tags: sql, datetime, h2

I am trying to extract the year and week number from H2 database to make it ISO compliant, which should also aggregate the results by weeks. I am using the below SQL statement

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR (PARSEDATETIME( TRUNC(COL_NAME),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')), \'-W\', WEEK( PARSEDATETIME( TRUNC(COL_NAME),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')))
```

Is this the right way to do it for H2 database. Are there any other ways or standard functions available in H2. Will this aggregate my results in weeks.

Also I want to set the start day of the week to Monday and hence I am changing the query as

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR (PARSEDATETIME( TRUNC(COL_NAME),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')), \'-W\', WEEK( PARSEDATETIME( TRUNC(COL_NAME),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'), 1))
```

However I am getting the following exception

> nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid parameter
>   count for "WEEK", expected count: "1";

Comment: Why not simply use: `FORMATDATETIME(col_name, 'yyyy-ww');`? But I don't think H2 supports ISO week and year e.g. for `2016-01-01` the ISO week is 53

Answer (score 2):

In h2 db one can extract week or year using the EXTRACT command. To extract the week, type:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM COLUMN NAME) FROM TABLE NAME
```

And to extract the year, type:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM COLUMN NAME) FROM TABLE NAME
```

The **TIMESTAMP** value of the column should in the standard format like **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**.